# Malformed URLs Issue

Tags: c#

I have a small piece of software that loads in .txt file of URLs, the problem is, if a url is malformed like: http://httpsite.com/ for example i get the error: system.uriformatexception the hostname could not be parsed.

```
    crawler = new Crawler(stops,
                          urls.Select(x => new Uri(x.StartsWith("http") ? x : "http://" + x)),
                          cancellationTokenSource.Token);
```

I can't think of a better way to check if the URL is OK to proceed or even ignore malformed URLs, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to fix a malformed URL.  Why not stop processing connection and report error?  You may want to check a URL if you have a server and want a user URL and want to check if it is valid before allowing it to be enters.  But once you are seeing a bad URL the best thing to do is ignored it.

Comment: Have you considered a try / catch block?